# How do I repair my Logitech Anywhere MX?

Tags: repair, logitech-mouse

My Anywhere Mouse has got *mushy mouse button syndrome*. That is, the left mouse button feels a little bit soft, and it easily double clicks, let's go when I drag something.

Before I repair it at home, rather than bringing it to the store (I kind of need it, it's the only one I have), I'd like to know exactly what I'm doing. It'd be too bad if I tried to repair it, voided the warranty and didn't succeed.

I'm guessing there are screws to open it under the rubber pads. And I suppose I can take those off without breaking them, and put them back on without bending them.

- How is this mouse held together, and what's the safest way to open it?
- Once I have it open, will I be able to fix the problem? What's causing the mushy mouse button?

Here's what I know so far:

- It might be the switch itself that's broken, in which case I shouldn't open it (I can't get a replacement, voiding the warranty to "have a look" seems pointless)
- If there are screws underneath the rubber pads, they're only on the 'front', the back two thirds of the mouse are all battery cover:

  [image]

  There's nothing I can see under the batteries either.
- In the mouse I had before this one, there were sort of springy things connecting the actual button with the switch soldered to the board. They were just lying inside of a bit of plastic, and I could swap the left and right ones easily. If repairing it is more difficult, transferring the problem to the right mouse button would be a very good start.

Comment: Tumbleweed Question!

Comment: I'm on my fourth replacement mouse.  :-(  They seem to be making these worse now.  Besides the plastic fix, has anyone found a stronger replacement microswitch?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks, Kristian, for the tip about the battery stickers. (I suspected, but was not sure)

This is the second Logitech mouse I've had the same problem with. The microswitch is not defect, because if I dismantle the top and actually press the microswitch with my fingers it works fine.

The problem is with the underside of the button where it meets the microswitch. This plastic is softer than the microswitch and with time the microswitch grinds a groove into the button, which is when the problems start, as the switch is then not completely pressed. I glue a very thin, hard foil over this groove and the problem goes away.

I guess it's too late for the original post, but I hope this helps other people searching for a solution to the same problem.

Comment: I actually have another logitech mouse with the exact same problem - it looks as if this piece of plastic is the mouse's "predetermined breaking point". :-(

I put the tiniest piece of electrical tape into the little furrow and the mouse works perfectly again (I feared glue might attack the plastic). Nice work spotting this. I bet it's more than these two models affected.

Answer (score 5):

Here's my fix, we've done 3 of these mice with this fix and it's worked each time.

### The Logitech Mouse Double Click Problem and How To Fix It

The blog post with images - http://www.redferret.net/?p=31008
The YouTube video - http://youtu.be/V66Cd2Y4IPs
[image: More pictures in the blogpost]

Hope that helps.

Comment: I've done this many times in the past and was surprised when I opened the mouse up. Anywhere MX has a smaller sealed microswitch that can't be disassembled.

Answer (score 3):

If you had the mouse for less than 3 years and still have the proof of purchase, contact Logitech and they will send you a new one (after asking for some minor and completely irrelevant troubleshooting).  Mine arrived a few days ago.  The original had a severe case of left button mushiness and would almost always generate a double-click.

Once the new one received, I dissected the old mouse, and found two screws, one under each of the sliding pads under the mouse's nose.  Back of the bottom part still firmly attached after removing the screws, though.

Comment: Fantastic, I didn't even think of that! I'll call them in the morning and post another comment.

Answer (score 2):

There are two more screws under the battery stickers.

However, the double click problem seems to be caused by a defect micro switch, which you should replace with a new one (solder) in order to repair.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to replace the micro switch, you need this one [E-Switch TS20100F070S](http://dilp.netcomponents.com/cgi-bin/e-switch.asp?partnumber1=ts2). Solder with a very small tip is recommended.

There is a great video which shows [Logitech Anywhere MX](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NLjEzmmtYMY) being disassembled and [iFixit guide](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Logitech-Mouse-Anywhere-MX-defect-micro-switch/10243).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Quickest and easiest fix for your broken Logitech mx Anywhere mouse.

Full video at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0eJblRVSQ7U

Simply super glue two piece of cardstock paper to the two worn in groves and everything works again.

I just fixed two of my broken mouses doing this method. No need to bend any metal. If you still have your receipt you can also get a replacement mouse sent before attempting this fix.

Answer (score 0):

You may check also my answer on [Logitech Anywhere MX button replacement](https://superuser.com/questions/565300/logitech-anywhere-mx-button-replacement).
I fixed mine just by re-soldering and raising the microswitch a bit. Whatever additional layer I add against a microswitch otherwise ends torn apart or moved away.