# Logitech Anywhere MX button replacement

Tags: repair, logitech-mouse

I have a Logitech Anywhere MX mouse. Its right button is not working properly and needs to be replaced. I have found in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/377259/how-do-i-repair-my-logitech-anywhere-mx) that the replacement button is [E-Switch TS20100F070S](http://dilp.netcomponents.com/cgi-bin/e-switch.asp?partnumber1=ts2).

The button part itself is very cheap but the shown shipping costs are more expensive than a brand new Anywhere MX mouse.

Are there cheap mouse models which uses compatible button parts so I can salvage them to repair my mouse?

Comment: This is a question that only Logitech could answer.

Comment: Just did my mouse using this [switch part from Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/Omron-switches-Terminal-Appliances-Replacement/dp/B00VZS72GG?ie=UTF8&psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o01_s01). And you can also get [replacement feet](http://www.amazon.com/Generic-Logitech-Anywhere-thickness-replacement-Pc/dp/B01F6I7HRY?ie=UTF8&psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o01_s01)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most probably can fix it yourself with any surface-mount microswitch that fits and that you can fix on the board. Make sure that the button is properly located and use some glue if needed to position it + wires to connect to the former pads. This is quite tricky but doable...

As for me, I first de-soldered one pad of the existing (partially) defective microswitch, raised it a bit with a very small flathead screwdriver while the solder was liquid and let it freeze in place. This reduced slightly the gap between the microswitch and the button. This probably will give more time before I need to replace it completely with a spare part.

**Warning again**: you may totally ruin the mouse, not even speaking of the warranty ;)

I was dumbly too zealous and wanted to do the same for the other microswitch end, but it stripped off completely the pad off the board... No way to make contact again here. But I was lucky to find the signal elsewhere on the mouse board and solder a very thin wire from there to the side of the microswitch that was no more in contact with the board... Warning again: I am not even sure this is the right place to get the proper signal, even though it worked fine for me at the end!

You'll have an image similar to [this](http://www.flickr.com/photos/mooncactus/9405287497/) but better not damage the board tracks in the first place ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have gone throught nearly all the suggested solutions up to replacing the microswitches, but nothing worked for me permanently.

My theory is that it has something to do with how the microswitches are connected to the board. They seem to lose contact after some time. I got some routine with quickly resoldering the connections of the microswitch a bit. This always works for some months up to a year before I have to repeat the procedure.

I'm reluctant to glue the microswitches to the board in case they actually become defunct. But maybe this could make the microswitches last longer between resoldering.

Resoldering takes about a minute with a hot soldering iron. I permanently removed the screws below the front gliding pads and only keep the two back screws below the (+) inscription in the battery compartment in place for quick access.